# Slower Runnable JAR performance in Java 8

Tags: performance, java-8, java-6

I have a Java solution created in Java 6 and have been compiling this in Eclipse using JDK 1.6.0_45. It is a Runnable JAR executed on a Thread by an external BPMN scheduling framework periodically. The JAR makes a series of calls as below:

1. REST calls to external c# webservice.
2. REST calls to Microsoft Project Server to retrieve Excel Reports.
3. Send emails via SMTP to a number of recipients.

The build was run on a linux server using the below Java Runtime Environment:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Due to a need to update to Java 8, I have recompiled the solution with Java-SE 1.8(JDK 1.8.0_121). I have also setup a linux server with the below JRE:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
```

What I see is a significant drop in JAR performance whereby the REST calls especially seem to be taking at least 4 times as long to execute than on Java 6, as well as any other actions such as reading an excel file in Java. Using 'top' I can see memory usage is mostly the same as on Java 6, only execution time overall has increased.

Does anybody know why this could be, are there any known issues with Java 8?

Comment: This could also very well be an environmental issue, as you indicated you have setup a new Linux server.

Comment: There was no requirement to recompile your code.

Comment: @DidierL That is possible, I will try a different JRE and observe the result.

Comment: @Holger We have to recompile as there had been security hardening on another external system which will not accept JDK6 based ciphers on request to its service.

Comment: That could have performance implications as well. So you have multiple changes, hence, lots of different possible reasons for performance differences…

Comment: I have identified one of the causes to be the Apache POI Excel workbook creation method 'new XSSFWorkbook(new File(filepath))'

I am using the latest version of the POI library but it is still slow to open. Have tried to use BufferedInputStream as opposed to FileInputStream and File, but no success.